# how ican make blueman automatic pair confirmation linux

Tags: linux, debian, bluetooth, rasberrypi

How can I make blueman automatically confirm pairing in linux when I try to connect to a rasberry pi using bluetooth? It shows a blueman pairing request confirmation. How can I deiable this and make it auto pair any device?

Comment: So you're wanting a device that automatically connects to any available BT device without prompting or confirming? If this is not what you're trying to do, could you clarify your question?

Comment: yap please how @music2myear

Comment: What's your use case? Why are you trying to do this? What problem are you trying to solve that leads you to believe this is the right way to solve it? Knowing that may help us better answer your question.